# Why is netezza nzload truncating csv line?

Tags: csv, netezza

I'm using nzload to load a CSV file into a Netezza table, and I'm getting an error that is puzzling to me.

The .log file says:

```
bad #: input row #(byte offset to last char examined) [field #, declaration] diagnostic, "text consumed"[last char examined]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: 964(25) [4, DOUBLE] missing field - fillRecord not enabled, "0"[0x0a<LF>]
```

The .bad file contains only:

```
963|2016-8-24|63.000000|0
```

However, the corresponding line in the CSV file is intact:

```
962|2016-8-24|62.000000|0.096200|0.192400|0.288600|0.384800|0.481000|962.000000|462.722000|"default"|3
963|2016-8-24|63.000000|0.096300|0.192600|0.288900|0.385200|0.481500|963.000000|463.684500|"default"|3
964|2016-8-24|64.000000|0.096400|0.192800|0.289200|0.385600|0.482000|964.000000|464.648000|"default"|3
```

So...  why is Netezza complaining?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm invoking nzload from a C++ program via "system".   The curious thing is that if I take the command string and execute it on the command line directly, then the nzload seems to work fine.

Comment: Not sure at this point, but please include the full nzload command

Comment: I had the same error about "missing field". In my case, there was a line break within a value, causing Netezza to interpret it as two, short rows instead of one full row.